# Matplotlib User Interface Example Breaks With More Than Three Patches

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib

I'm working with this [Matplotlib User Interface example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/svg_tooltip.html), and when I run the base example it works as advertised. As I start to adapt it to my needs, things start to go sideways.

- When I add a third patch, it still works as advertised.
- When I add a fourth patch, its mouseover seems to be mapped to the subplot X axis top instead of the patch.
- When I add a fifth patch, the fourth is still mapped to the subplot X axis top and I can't find the mouseover area for the fifth patch.

I'm unable to figure out what makes the script angry when patches > 3. Looking at the script, it seems like it should work for any number of patches. The SVG displays the same behavior in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

[Python 2.7.10, Matplotlib 1.3.1]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.add_patch(mpatches.FancyBboxPatch((1980, 1), 1, 1, boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("Round", pad=0.15)))
ax1.annotate('One', xy=(1980, 1), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points', color='w', ha='center', fontsize=8, bbox=dict(boxstyle='round, pad=.5', fc=(.1, .1, .1, .92), ec=(1., 1., 1.), lw=1, zorder=1))

ax1.add_patch(mpatches.FancyBboxPatch((1990, 2), 1, 1, boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("Round", pad=0.15)))
ax1.annotate('Two', xy=(1990, 2), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points', color='w', ha='center', fontsize=8, bbox=dict(boxstyle='round, pad=.5', fc=(.1, .1, .1, .92), ec=(1., 1., 1.), lw=1, zorder=1))

ax1.add_patch(mpatches.FancyBboxPatch((2000, 3), 1, 1, boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("Round", pad=0.15)))
ax1.annotate('Three', xy=(2000, 3), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points', color='w', ha='center', fontsize=8, bbox=dict(boxstyle='round, pad=.5', fc=(.1, .1, .1, .92), ec=(1., 1., 1.), lw=1, zorder=1))

ax1.add_patch(mpatches.FancyBboxPatch((2010, 4), 1, 1, boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("Round", pad=0.15)))
ax1.annotate('Four', xy=(2010, 4), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points', color='w', ha='center', fontsize=8, bbox=dict(boxstyle='round, pad=.5', fc=(.1, .1, .1, .92), ec=(1., 1., 1.), lw=1, zorder=1))

# Save the figure in a fake file object
ax1.set_xlim(1970, 2017)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 8)

# Set id for the patches
for i, t in enumerate(ax1.patches):
    t.set_gid('patch_%d' % i)

# Set id for the annotations
for i, t in enumerate(ax1.texts):
    t.set_gid('tooltip_%d' % i)

f = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(f, format="svg")

# --- Add interactivity ---

# Create XML tree from the SVG file.
tree, xmlid = ET.XMLID(f.getvalue())
tree.set('onload', 'init(evt)')

# Hide the tooltips
for i, t in enumerate(ax1.texts):
    el = xmlid['tooltip_%d' % i]
    el.set('visibility', 'hidden')

# Assign onmouseover and onmouseout callbacks to patches.
for i, t in enumerate(ax1.patches):
    el = xmlid['patch_%d' % i]
    el.set('onmouseover', "ShowTooltip(this)")
    el.set('onmouseout', "HideTooltip(this)")

# This is the script defining the ShowTooltip and HideTooltip functions.
script = """
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[

    function init(evt) {
        if ( window.svgDocument == null ) {
            svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
            }
        }

    function ShowTooltip(obj) {
        var cur = obj.id.slice(-1);

        var tip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip_' + cur);
        tip.setAttribute('visibility',"visible")
        }

    function HideTooltip(obj) {
        var cur = obj.id.slice(-1);
        var tip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip_' + cur);
        tip.setAttribute('visibility',"hidden")
        }

    ]]>
    </script>
    """

# Insert the script at the top of the file and save it.
tree.insert(0, ET.XML(script))
ET.ElementTree(tree).write('svg_tooltip_1.svg')
```

[ETA: Output Paths]

Exploring the output paths, I get this, which shows something is clearly wrong with the fourth path.

Path 1:

```
   <path clip-path="url(#p7ff5b81e1d)" d=" M161.28 352.08 L170.208 352.08 Q171.547 352.08 171.547 345.6 L171.547 302.4 Q171.547 295.92 170.208 295.92 L161.28 295.92 Q159.941 295.92 159.941 302.4 L159.941 345.6 Q159.941 352.08 161.28 352.08 z " style="fill:#0000ff;stroke:#000000;"/>


</g>
```

Path 2:

```
   <path clip-path="url(#p7ff5b81e1d)" d=" M250.56 308.88 L259.488 308.88 Q260.827 308.88 260.827 302.4 L260.827 259.2 Q260.827 252.72 259.488 252.72 L250.56 252.72 Q249.221 252.72 249.221 259.2 L249.221 302.4 Q249.221 308.88 250.56 308.88 z " style="fill:#0000ff;stroke:#000000;"/>


</g>
```

Path 3:

```
   <path clip-path="url(#p7ff5b81e1d)" d=" M339.84 265.68 L348.768 265.68 Q350.107 265.68 350.107 259.2 L350.107 216 Q350.107 209.52 348.768 209.52 L339.84 209.52 Q338.501 209.52 338.501 216 L338.501 259.2 Q338.501 265.68 339.84 265.68 z " style="fill:#0000ff;stroke:#000000;"/>


</g>
```

Path 4:

```
   <path d=" M72 43.2 L518.4 43.2" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;"/>


</g>
```

[image: High Quality Image of Behavior]

Comment: This is extremely weird, especially as it only depends on the number of patches/texts (e.g. leaving out the first one makes it work for the fourth one).

Comment: I know, right?  I've done any manner of permutations and can not figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to conclude that the [svg_tooltip example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/svg_tooltip.html)  from the matplotlib page is wrong.

The problem comes from the lines

```
for i, t in enumerate(ax.patches):
    t.set_gid('patch_%d' % i)
```

which iterate over the patches in the axes and add an id called `patch_id` to the them. However, the axes may have many more patches than the one we added in the code. E.g. the axes spines are patches as well. So when iterating over all patches, we may incidently set the id `"patch_4"` to an axis spine instead of the patch we want to set it to.

To overcome this problem, we actually need to set the id to exactly the patch which should have it, e.g. by iterating only over the added patches.

Second problem here: The id `patch_id` is also used by other elements in the canvas when saving. So we should call it differently, e.g. `mypatch_id`.

Next problem is when setting the visibilities and the callbacks, we should also not iterate over all texts and patches in the canvas, but instead only over those which have an id that we have set ourselves.

See below for a complete working example.

```
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()


years = [1980,1990, 2000, 2010]
labels = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

for i, year in enumerate(years):
    patch = mpatches.FancyBboxPatch((year, i+1), 1, 1, 
                        boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("Round", pad=0.15))
    annotate = ax1.annotate(labels[i], xy=(year, i+1), xytext=(0, 0), 
                    textcoords='offset points', color='w', ha='center', 
                    fontsize=8, bbox=dict(boxstyle='round, pad=.5', fc=(.1, .1, .1, .92), 
                    ec=(1., 1., 1.), lw=1, zorder=1))

    ax1.add_patch(patch)
    patch.set_gid('mypatch_{:03d}'.format(i))
    annotate.set_gid('mytooltip_{:03d}'.format(i))


# Save the figure in a fake file object
ax1.set_xlim(1970, 2017)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 8)


f = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(f, format="svg")

# --- Add interactivity ---

# Create XML tree from the SVG file.
tree, xmlid = ET.XMLID(f.getvalue())
tree.set('onload', 'init(evt)')


for i, y in enumerate(years):
    # Hide the tooltips
    tooltip = xmlid['mytooltip_{:03d}'.format(i)]
    tooltip.set('visibility', 'hidden')
    # Assign onmouseover and onmouseout callbacks to patches.
    mypatch = xmlid['mypatch_{:03d}'.format(i)]
    mypatch.set('onmouseover', "ShowTooltip(this)")
    mypatch.set('onmouseout', "HideTooltip(this)")

# This is the script defining the ShowTooltip and HideTooltip functions.
script = """
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[

    function init(evt) {
        if ( window.svgDocument == null ) {
            svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
            }
        }

    function ShowTooltip(obj) {
        var cur = obj.id.split("_")[1];
        var tip = svgDocument.getElementById('mytooltip_' + cur);
        tip.setAttribute('visibility',"visible")
        }

    function HideTooltip(obj) {
        var cur = obj.id.split("_")[1];
        var tip = svgDocument.getElementById('mytooltip_' + cur);
        tip.setAttribute('visibility',"hidden")
        }

    ]]>
    </script>
    """

# Insert the script at the top of the file and save it.
tree.insert(0, ET.XML(script))
ET.ElementTree(tree).write('svg_tooltip_2.svg')
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  Thanks very much for sussing the problem and for providing a solution that works perfectly.  Your solution also solves the conundrum of how to add more patches later that exist independently of the interface.  Outstanding.

Comment: p.s. I filed a note on GitHub highlighting the problem, your solution and begging credit go to you.

Comment: Just a note that the script works great while patches are 10 or less.  When the 11th patch is applied, the SVG will display the tooltip associated with the first patch.  I suspect it's the `obj.id.slice(-1)` from the original matplotlib example script.

Comment: Outstanding.  I had already converted my working code to {} formatting, but hadn't figured out the ecmascript revisions needed.  Thanks so much.  This adjustment should become part of the PR on Git.